# Teradata: how to convert varchar value (format 'dd.mm.yyyy') to date (format 'yyyy-mm-dd' )?

Tags: sql, date, teradata, varchar

how to convert varchar value, containing date in dd.mm.yyyy format, into date format 'yyyy-mm-dd' in WHERE clause in Teradata ?
Need to code something like this:

```
SELECT * from TABLE
WHERE <some operations with VARCHAR variable containing date> between '2015-06-01' and '2017-12-31'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to apply a format during the cast, either Teradata style:

```
WHERE CAST(str AS DATE FORMAT 'dd.mm.yyyy') 
BETWEEN DATE '2015-06-01' AND DATE '2017-12-31'
```

or Oracle style:

```
WHERE TO_DATE(str, 'dd.mm.yyyy') 
BETWEEN DATE '2015-06-01' AND DATE '2017-12-31'
```

Btw, I added `DATE` in front of the string, it's the recommended (and always reliable) way to write a date literal.